# How do i remove timezone from Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

Jekyll `post.date` or `site.date` seems to automatically have the timezone mentioned, is there any way I could change this? Or at least change timezone to UTC?

**In Linux  Env*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the timezone in `_config.yml` like this:

```
timezone: UTC
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones for other values (TZ column)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Liquid [`date` filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/) to format the date however you like:

```
{{ post.date | date: "%a, %b %d, %y" }}
```

>

```
Mon, Oct 10, 16
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works for custom formatting. But any idea who do i tweak sitemap?

Comment: How are you generating the sitemap?